# php order by 2 parameters

Tags: php

I need to order the list as follows;

- First the shops which are featured (featured shops have values >1 in "order_no") should be ordered according to order_no values
- After featured shops, the regular shops ("order_no"=1) should be ordered ascending by "title" (alphabetical order)

Here are some part of the code;

```
const DEFAULT_ORDER_COLUMN = "title";
const DEFAULT_ORDER_BY = "asc";

public function category() {
    $orderColumn = isset( $_GET['column'] ) && in_array($_GET['column'], $this->orderColum) ? $_GET['column'] : self::DEFAULT_ORDER_COLUMN;
    $orderBy = isset( $_GET['order'] ) && in_array($_GET['order'], $this->orderBy) ? $_GET['order'] : self::DEFAULT_ORDER_BY;
    $params['total'] = $search->rowCount();
    $params['result'] = $search->fetchAll();
    template::add_content(template::load('homepage/category', $params));
}
```

I tried to get this issue done with this code

```
if ( isset( $_GET['order_no'] ) ) != 1 {
const DEFAULT_ORDER_COLUMN = "order";
const DEFAULT_ORDER_BY = "desc";
} else {
const DEFAULT_ORDER_COLUMN = "title";
const DEFAULT_ORDER_BY = "asc";
}
```

but did not work. What would be the solution?

Comment: Are you using a framework of some sort?

Comment: You need to show the sql as you can do it there. And `$search` is undefined in your function.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your criteria, you need the following order clause:

```
ORDER BY `order_no` DESC, `title`
```

However, from your code it is not clear how you are building your sql and how the `$_GET` variables are related to your question.